# How do you update code using loadTemplates for the new Heist API?

Tags: haskell, heist

This code was working with Heist prior to the 0.10.0 change

```
main = do
      Right ts <- loadTemplates "templates" $
          bindSplices mySplices defaultHeistState
      etc..
```

Now I get the error

```
testdb.hs:59:33: Not in scope: `defaultHeistState'
```

I know the type signature for loadTemplates has changed to

```
loadTemplates :: FilePath -> EitherT [String] IO TemplateRepoSource
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to adapt my old code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it to work with this, but I'm open to more elegant ways of doing this

```
load baseDir splices = do
    tmap <- runEitherT  $ do
        templates <- loadTemplates baseDir
        let hc = HeistConfig mySplices  [] [] [] templates
        initHeist hc
    either (error . concat) return tmap

main = do
      ts <- load "templates" $ bindSplices mySplices 
      renderWithArgs [("test", T.pack "hello world")]  ts "index" >>= 
        B.putStr . maybe "Page not found" (toByteString . fst)
```

Comment: This is the right approach.  With the addition of compiled splices, we had to have a way of specifying things to be bound before Heist initializes.  That's why there's a separate HeistConfig and initHeist.

Comment: If you can accept your answer so this question doesn't show up as unanswered, that would be great.